# hibernate validator custom constraint throws exception, how to catch it in spring when using @Valid?

Tags: java, spring, validation, exception, hibernate-validator

I have a subsystem in a web application that performs an interactive validation on a signup process, so when a user types an username, email, password, etc. there is an async request to the server to perform the validation, and then returns a response.

One of the validations performed for username or emails is that they aren't used already for any other user, meaning a query to the database is required, this is why i choose to perform the validation on the server side. I'm using Spring Framework 4.1, Spring Data and Hibernate Validator 5.1.

For the available username and email validations, following the HV reference guide i created custom constraints annotations (only showing username one):

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UniqueUsername {
    String message() default "{}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

and validator class:

```
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername,String> {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UniqueUsernameValidator(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername annotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // this should be checked with @NotNull at field level
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(value);
        if (user == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

So when the user types into a form field, there are AJAX requests with jQuery where i serialize the entire form and send it on a POST request that i capture with a @RestController like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup/validation/{field}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> validateField(
        @PathVariable("field") String field,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") UserRegistrationForm registrationForm,
        BindingResult result,
        Locale locale) {
    ...
}
```

**Question 1**: In case the repository throws a DataAccessException in the validator class, is there a way to catch it at the rest controller when using the @Valid annotation?

**Question 2**: Is there anything wrong with this approach?

**Note**: I'm not catching the DataAccessException in the validator class because i wan't it to propagate and be able to catch it on the controller so i can return an appropiate HTTP 500 code with the ResponseEntity return value and inform the user there has been some issue with the validation, because if the database is down for some reason, the signup request will fail to be persisted aswell.

**Note**: I could get a validator instance inside the @RestController method and then perform the validation right there, and be able to catch the exception easy, which is the workaround i'm using right now, but i'd like to avoid this for the sake of reducing boilerplate and code duplication.

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer to your original question?

Comment: Its been quite a while, but no I remember it was a battle I did not win